# IBM Informix SQL Syntax assistance

Tags: sql, informix

Wondering if anyone may be able to help me with some SQL here.  I'm tasked with retrieving some data from a legacy DB system - It's an IBM Informix DB running v7.23C1.  It may well be that what I'm trying to do here is pretty simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I'm used to MS SQL Server, rather than any other DB system and this one seems quite old: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/3731.pdf (?)

Basically, I just want to run a query that includes nesting, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  So for example, I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT cmprod.cmp_product, 
 (stock.stk_stkqty - stock.stk_allstk) stk_bal, 
    stock.stk_ospurch, 
    stock.stk_backord,
    'Current Sales Period',
    'Current Period -1',
    'Current Period -2',
    cmprod.cmp_curcost,
    stock.stk_credate,
    stock.stk_lastpurch,
    stock.stk_binref
FROM informix.stock stock,
     informix.cmprod cmprod
WHERE stock.stk_product = cmprod.cmp_product
   AND (cmp_category = 'VOLV'
   OR cmp_category = 'VOLD'
   OR cmp_category = 'VOLA')
   AND stk_loc = 'ENG';
```

Now, basically where I have values like 'Current Period -1' I want to include a nested field which will run a query to get the sales within a given date range.  I'm sure I can put those together separately, but can't seem to get the compiler to be happy with my code when executed altogether.

Probably something like (NB, this specific query is for another column, but you get the idea):

```
SELECT s.stmov_product, s.stmov_trandate, s.stmov_qty
FROM informix.stmove s
WHERE s.stmov_product = '1066823'
AND s.stmov_qty > 0
AND s.stmov_trandate IN (
     SELECT MAX(r.stmov_trandate) 
     FROM informix.stmove r
     WHERE r.stmov_product = '1066823'
     AND r.stmov_qty > 0)
```

What makes things a little worse is I don't have access to the server that this DB is running on.  At the moment I have a custom C# app that connects via an ODBC driver and executes the raw SQL, parsing the results back into a .CSV.

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under all circumstances, Informix 7.23 is so geriatric that it is unkind to be still running it.  It is not clear whether this is an OnLine (Informix Dynamic Server, IDS) or SE (Standard Engine) database. However, 7.23 was the version prior to the Y2K-certified 7.24 releases, so it is 15 years old or thereabouts, maybe a little older.

The syntaxes supported by Informix servers back in the days of 7.23 were less comprehensive than they are in current versions.  Consequently, you'll need to be careful.  You should have the manuals for the server — someone, somewhere in your company should.  If not, you'll need to try finding it in the graveyard manuals section of the IBM Informix web pages (start at http://www.informix.com/ for simplicity of URL; however, archaic manuals take some finding, but you should be able to get there from http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ifxhelp/v0/index.jsp choosing 'Servers' in the LHS).

If you are trying to write:

```
SELECT ...
       (SELECT ... ) AS 'Current - 1',
       (SELECT ... ) AS 'Current - 2',
       ...
  FROM ...
```

then you need to study the server SQL Syntax for 7.23 to know whether it is allowed.  AFAICR, OnLine (Informix Dynamic Server) would allow it and SE probably would not, but that is far from definitive.  I simply don't remember what the limitations were in that ancient a version.

---

Judging from the 7.2 [Informix Guide to SQL: Syntax](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/7882a.pdf) manual (dated April 1996 — 17 years old), you cannot put a `(SELECT ...)` in the select-list in this version of Informix.

You may have to create a temporary table holding the results you want (along with appropriate key information), and then select from the temporary table in the main query.

This sort of thing is one of the problems with not updating your server for so long.

Comment: Yea, that is what I'm trying to do ultimately.  I agree it needs replaced, but that's not something I'm able to do.  I may be best to strip all of the data I need into memory and deal with it myself, rather than try to be clever about it in Informix SQL.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Jonathan - you're preaching to the choir about the upgrade! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be blunt, but can you at least have mercy on us by shortening the syntax?.. table.columns can be presented AS aliases. Meanwhile, if you cant upgrade to a newer version of Informix, you will have to rely on one or more SELECT INTO temp table queries in order to achieve your objective, which BTW, would make your coding more portable across different versions. You also have to evaluate whether using TEMP tables implies unacceptable processing times.